# Line-breaks in multiple-line textbox won't show in email notifications

Tags: cognito-forms

Line-breaks in multiple line textbox will show as a single line in email notifications. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The same issue occurs when including the field in a content area on the form or the confirmation page.  I will cover some of the possible solutions to this.  Please comment on this answer to provide feedback.

1. The text captured from a multiple line textbox contains line breaks, but HTML just treats these as spaces, so when shown in a content field or HTML email message, the line breaks are ignored.
2. The line breaks cannot be converted into HTML 
    tags when edited, as this would mess up other usages of the data, like exports to Excel, which rely on the data existing as entered.  Also, we have logic in place to prevent HTML and script injection attacks that would remove this content anyway, which is in place to protect our customers.
3. We could convert line breaks to 
    tags when building email messages and content areas on the form for these fields.  This would leave the data intact.  However, this would only apply to line breaks (no other formatting) and also would not be something that could be turned off.
4. We could also add optional support for markdown (similar to what I am typing now) and support both line breaks and a variety of limited syntax formatting.  The advantage to this is it would be an option that could be turned off, but is not obvious to most users.

Again, definitely an issue with no workaround at present, but hopefully this provides some perspective on the issues and possible solutions.  Please let us know your thoughts.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer. Option 3 would be fully acceptable. Doesn't matter if it can't be turned off. To me enter key = line break. If you don't want line breaks in the output, don't hit enter. But I guess some users would need markdown (option 4) for more syntax formatting.

Comment: Any chance option 3 would be included in next release?

Comment: It is on our triage board for consideration as a hotfix.  We will likely have 2-3 releases this week.  I will update you here as this progresses.

Comment: Hi Jamie, I tested yesterday, line breaks are not here yet. Any idea when we'll get a hotfix for this?

Comment: This item was promoted to our next feature release, as the team determined that it impacted too many aspects of the system (confirmation page, all emails, entry management) to rush out as a hotfix.  Our next feature release is getting close (it specifically adds Zapier support) but will be another week or two.

Comment: Sorry to insist, do you have an EDA for your next feature release?

Comment: I was just informed that our Zapier beta release just went out, which includes support for appropriate formatting of text with line breaks both on the form (content fields and read only views) and email messages.  Please check it out and mark this as the answer if this is now working for you.

Comment: Any example for "line break" in email verification message? I still didn't get it

Comment: Option 4 would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example works for me:

```
<body>
    HELLO<br/>
    <br/>
    YOU ARE WELCOME!<br/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the answer from @Steve works.

Here is the email I got

[image]

And here is the text I added to the template.

```
<body>
    HELLO<br/>
    <br/>
    YOU ARE WELCOME!<br/>

{####}
    <br/>
{##Link##}
    <br/>
{##verify Link##}
    <br/>

</body>
```

While you are testing, you can just click on the link at the bottom (don't click Continue) to continue sending emails with the latest version of the template until you are happy with the result.

[image]

After some tests, my template looks like

```
<body>
<br>
Hello!
<br><br>
It seems you are creating an account on blahblah
<br><br>
Please click the link below to verify your email address. 
<br><br>
{##Click to verify your email##} 
<br><br>
After that, you can login on blahblah
<br><br>
blahblah
<br><br>
</body>
```